# Headers are missed when appending multiple dataframes into a list to make one concatenated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code where 5 dataframes are being generated and I want to combine all the dataframes into one, but since they have different headers of the columns, i think appending it to the list are not retaining the header names instead it is providing numbers.
Is there any other solution to combine the dataframes keeping the header names as it is?
Thanks in advance!!

```
list=[]
i=0
while i<5:
    df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    list.append(df)
    i=i+1
df_concat=pd.concat(list,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a common column in the dataframes that you can merge on? In that case - use the data frame merge function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

I've had to do this recently with two dataframes I had, and I merged on the date column.

Are you trying to add additional columns, or append each dataframe on top of each other?

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas
This link will give you an overview of the different functions you might need to use.

You can also rename the columns, if they do contain the same sort of data.  Without an example of the dataframe it's tricky to know.

Comment: It's done. I created a dictionary and then in every dictionary I had my tables which I needed to concatenate horizontally. So with dict={}, dict[0] contained data of first table and dict[1] contains data of second table and post that I created a new dataframe=pd.concat(dict,axis=1).

Comment: Yes it's my bad. I didn't provide enough details and examples. But thank you for your time. Really appreciate it!!